# Is it possible to erase source history in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I create a branch and give some contractors access to it. Then I realize there are hard coded credentials I would rather them not see so I take them out and check in the changes. Of course, they could potentially look at the history and see it anyway.

What do I do? Is it necessary to create the branch from scratch again or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove the history without destroying the files. What you could do is to destroy the file from the commandline `tf vc destroy $/Path/to/file` then check in a fresh copy of the file at the end of the history. Or destroy the whole branch and create a new one that doesn't contain the file with the credentials.

Comment: Does the GUI provide a way to destroy the file? I'm probably gonna spend like 15 minutes trying to figure out the right $/Path/to/file if it doesn't. Or maybe it would only take a couple seconds but a previous experience trying to unlock a file left me with no desire to ever try using the command line again.

Comment: The tfs source control explorer extensions for visual studio provides this through UI. Plus, you need admin permissions to destroy data.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HolanJan.TFSSourceControlExplorerExtension-11508

Answer (score 3):

Destroy command is the way but I can find very easy and useful to add the "[TFS Source control Explorer extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/924f4281-cf75-4ffe-899d-29ebcede3034/view/Reviews)" ([here version from previous VS version)](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/af70cbb7-1e0d-4d16-bc57-cccc15370c51My) to Visual Studio.

It has a lot of feature **easy to use from VS source control GUI** and also Destroy Work Item function from right click menu: advanced->Destroy.Then in confirmation dialog you can choose if or not keep related history information.

Enjoy!